# Extjs: How to change tree node attributes?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I change the attributes of a tree node?

One tree node has the following attributes:

```
{"id":"75",
"description":"My Tree Node",
"status":"25"
"uiProvider":"col",
"leaf":true}
```

Now my script receives the following data

```
{
"id":"75",
"status":"100",
"cls":"done"
}
```

I try to update the attributes (**UPDATED**):

```
// a.result.data has the new data and taskID is the node's id
for (var property in a.result.data)
{ 
  tree.getNodeById(taskID).attributes[property] = a.result.data[property];
}
```

The tree, however, does not get updated.

How can I make the tree show the changes?
I need the node to change existing attributes and add the new attributes.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: a.result.data.property might be a bad way to access it.. getting undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [extjs forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?36430-How-to-render-TreeNode-after-changing-node.attributes):

```
function refreshNodeColumns(n)
{
    var t = n.getOwnerTree();
    var a = n.attributes;
    var cols = t.columns;
    var el = n.ui.getEl().firstChild; // <div class="x-tree-el">
    var cells = el.childNodes;

    //<div class="x-tree-col"><div class="x-tree-col-text">

    for(var i = 1, len = cols.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        var d = cols[i].dataIndex;
        var v = (a[d]!=null)? a[d] : '';
        if (cols[i].renderer) v = cols[i].renderer(v);
        cells[i].firstChild.innerHTML = v;        
    }
}
```

Should work if you call it after your update loop.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and it doesn't do anything. Firebug says not js errors.

Comment: I got this to work. The function updated all the columns except for the Text column. For that I had to use node.setText(a.result.data.description)

Comment: Thanks man, this is pure gold! You saved my day... Now can be a restful Friday :D